# How to find ItemIndex of outer repeater when user click radio button in the inner repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a nested repeater and need to findout the ItemIndex of the outer repeater when user click the radio button in the inner repeater. 
I tried using rb.parent.parent and also rb.NamingContainer.NamingContainer but I got casting error. 
I also searched different sites regarding similar problems but they were not a solution for mine.
Any comment is highly appreciated.

```
protected void rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rptrSubscriptions = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrSubscriptions");
    if (rptrSubscriptions != null)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == (ListItemType.Item) || e.Item.ItemType == (ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DataTable SubscriptionTbl = SubscriptionsBind(SelectedLanguageID, SelectedPlatformID, SelectedCurrencyID, SelectedGroupID, 1); 
            rptrSubscriptions.DataSource = SubscriptionTbl;
            rptrSubscriptions.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void HighlightSubscription(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = source as RadioButton;
    int CurrentrepeaterItemIndex = ((RepeaterItem)rb.NamingContainer).ItemIndex;

    // save current row index in a hiddden field
    hiddenSelectedSubscriptionRowIndex.Value = CurrentrepeaterItemIndex.ToString();

    int ParentRepeaterItemIndex = ((RepeaterItem)rb.NamingContainer.NamingContainer).ItemIndex;
hiddenSelectedSubscriptionGroupRowIndex.Value = ParentRepeaterItemIndex.ToString();
}

<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptionGroups" runat="server"     OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptions" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptions_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptions_ItemCommand">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSubscription" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="HighlightSubscription" AutoPostBack="true"/>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Hi again can you test this                                                                      foreach(RepeaterItem b in rptrSubscriptionGroups.Items)
           {
               lblitemindex.Text = b.ItemIndex.ToString();
           }

Comment: Hi again Nikolay :) Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately it will loop through all of the rows in the outer repeater and I don't understand which one is related to current inner one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you have tried with `Parent.Parent` but I think that you can do it with it :

```
int CurrentrepeaterItemIndex = ((RepeaterItem)rb.Parent.Parent.Parent).ItemIndex;
```

The First Parent is going one level up to the ItemTemplate :

```
<ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSubscription" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="HighlightSubscription" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

The Second Parent is going again one level up to the inner Repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptions" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptions_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptions_ItemCommand">
```

The Third Parent is going to the outer Repeater item and you can get the item index.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptionGroups" runat="server"     OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. I did the changes that you suggested but I get error :Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem'. Please advice.

Comment: ok you have some table in the item template or something like this

Comment: Dear Nikolay, Your solution works absolutely fine and the point that you noted that I have to go three levels upper is correct, just I changed Parent to NamingContainer and it worked fine. I realy appreciate your reply :)